# stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: laravel

This question has been asked many times before. But none of them helped me solve the problem.

This is the query I wrote:

```
    $this->data['model'] = OrderDetail::with('product')->groupBy(['service_id',function($q){
         return Carbon::parse($q->created_at)->format('Y');
    }]);

    $this->data['data'] = $this->data['model']->paginate(request()->get('limit', $this->data['limit']))->appends(request()->all());
```

When I perform Paginate operation, I encounter such an error

it gives the same error when I do `dd($this->data)`

the whole error message:[image]

Comment: Can you dd or debug your $this->data?

Comment: For me it is not clear where the error occurs. Can you show the whole error message, please?

Comment: I made edits to the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Are you sure you declared right the variable $this->data['model']  before asigning a value?**
What is the declaration? Because, from Laravel point of view, the returning Object of OrderDetail is kind of StdClass. If you just redeclare the row like this:

> $rowsSelected = OrderDetail::

The variable $rowsSelected will automatically be declared as the right Object.
Otherwise you will ever get an error.

later edit, try this:

```
$this->data['model'] = new \stdClass();
```

Comment: I did $this->data['model'] = new OrderDetail() but the result did not change

Comment: I told you to declare the $this->data['model'] BEFORE asigning a value!!! Try with $this->data['model'] = new \stdClass(); and then $this->data['model'] = OrderDetail::

Comment: I tried that too but nothing changed

Comment: Where is your data defined? $data = ??